# Yii: How do you abort model validation in the middle, after one of the rules returns FALSE?

Tags: validation, yii, model, yii-validation

In `Yii` framework, how do you `abort` any `further validation` after one of rules returns `FALSE` ?

What I am trying to achieve is:

1) stopping unnecessary MySQL queries after we know that a model didn't pass the validation.

2) cleaner, easy to understand error messages for the web user, without sorting them manually in the controller.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: are you trying validation with the validate() method? coz if you are, then i don't think there are any queries done by the validate method, not sure about it though.

Comment: I'm doing both the `validate()` and `save()` validations. Many validations are custom methods querying database, and some of the built-in ones (`unique`, `exists`) I believe do query MySQL, too.

Comment: i stand corrected, some obviously do queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: there is no global setting or solution: If you look at CActiveRecord::validate(), you can see all validators are called and executed.

You can prevent running multiple validations for the same attribute. You would have to set skipOnError=true for all the validation rules.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator/#skipOnError-detail

> whether this validation rule should be skipped when there is already a
>   validation error for the current attribute. Defaults to false.

I think a global option could be added to Yii (quite easily actually).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

For users browsing this thread:

The `validate()` method - to be extended in your custom AR class - is located in `yii/framework/base/CModel`, line 150.